# Searching values through Pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas

This is a sample of a pandas dataframe I have. I need to find the particular row for a given bid. For instance, give bid = 5, I need to return row corresponding to that in the following table. If I enter a missing bid, for instance, bid = 6, then the row corresponding to the largest bid smaller than input bid should be return. Thus row corresponding to bid = 5 should be return in that case. How do I do this in pandas?

```
Bid Imp Click   Spend
3   13  0.97    2
4   13  1.89    7
5   79  34.98   130
7   83  37.52   140
8   88  38.52   144
```

Comment: I think `df.iloc[np.searchsorted(df.Bid, value)]`

Comment: If any answer solves your issue, could you mark it as valid with the green tick? @dineshdileep

Comment: @MabelVillalba apologies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this could do the trick:

```
>>> df[(df['Bid']<=5)].iloc[-1,:]

Bid        5.00
Imp       79.00
Click     34.98
Spend    130.00
Name: 2, dtype: float64
```

If you want a pandas just do `df[(df['Bid']<=5)].iloc[-1,:].to_frame().T`.

```
>>> df[(df['Bid']<=5)].iloc[-1,:].to_frame().T
   Bid   Imp  Click  Spend
2  5.0  79.0  34.98  130.0
```

For the case of the missing bid=6, `df[(df['Bid']<=6)].iloc[-1,:].to_frame().T` would return the nearest bid below 6, which is, again,  5.

```
>>> df[(df['Bid']<=6)].iloc[-1,:].to_frame().T
   Bid   Imp  Click  Spend
2  5.0  79.0  34.98  130.0
```

**EDITED**
To make sure that the dataframe contains `Bid`in ascending order just do previously:

```
>>> df = df.sort_values(by='Bid',ascending=True)
```

Comment: This will only work if the bids are ordered in ascending order.

Comment: Thought it was a pre-requisite, it can be solved by just `df.sort_values(by='Bid',ascending=True)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
def get_bid(val):
    # find the index of the maximum bid below or equal val
    index = df.loc[df.Bid <= val, 'Bid'].idxmax()
    return df.loc[[index]]
```

here is the result of calling the function with values 6 and 5 and 4 respectively

```
In []: get_bid(6)
Out[]: 
   Bid  Imp  Click  Spend
2    5   79  34.98    130

In []: get_bid(5)
Out[]: 
   Bid  Imp  Click  Spend
2    5   79  34.98    130

In []: get_bid(4)
Out[]: 
   Bid  Imp  Click  Spend
1    4   13   1.89      7
```

PS if you prefer one liners, you can change the code to In[1], this will produce the same output as above. i.e. a dataframe. removing the double brackets(In [2]) will change the output to a series. I,e,

```
In [1]: val = 6
       df.loc[[df.loc[df.Bid <= val, 'Bid'].idxmax()]]
Out[1]: 
   Bid  Imp  Click  Spend
2    5   79  34.98    130

In [2]: df.loc[df.loc[df.Bid <= val, 'Bid'].idxmax()]
Out[2]: 
Bid        5.00
Imp       79.00
Click     34.98
Spend    130.00
Name: 2, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generator-based method. The generator gets exhausted and we catch the last item by enumeration.

```
df = df.sort_values('Bids')
df.loc[df['Bid'] == [max(enumerate(i for i in df['Bid'] if i <= 6))[1]]]

   Bid  Imp  Click  Spend
2    5   79  34.98    130
```

The above method is slow for large, marginally faster for small dataframes. As an alternative, you can use this pandas-based solution:

```
df.iloc[df[df['Bid'] <= 6].index[-1]]
```

Comment: This will only work if the bids are ordered in ascending order